# X-Editable: Attach event to data change

Tags: jquery, x-editable

How to attach events to any data changes in fields done using XEditable? If not if there is any other plugin that allows that kind of behavior?

Comment: is this document http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html ll help u someway???

Comment: nope... all that has is just what are types of elements they support not how to attach events to data change... tried searching in documentation but it didnt helped

Comment: Can you be more precise please : Do you want an event to be fired when the user changes data without saving ? Or changing data after saving ? (ignoring unchanged saved data) And is it for an input text ? or datepicker ? ...

Comment: well i am interested in firing events when user changes data whether or not that data was saved (saving is sending to server which i dont care), i am interested in UI level events

Answer (score 8):

I am using `Angular-xeditable`, And i am able to bind events and add other attributes too.
Add `e-onChange="alert('I am Fired')"` to your needed HTML Tag.
For Example:

```
<a href="#" editable-text="user.name" e-onChange="alert('I am Fired')" e-style="color: green" e-required e-placeholder="Enter name">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cg3pLmed/

And by JavaScript

```
$('#username').on('save', function(e, params) {
     alert('Saved value: ' + params.newValue);
});
```

Fired when new value was submitted. You can use `$(this).data('editable')` to access to editable instance. Check with the Events in the following link
http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html

Comment: <a href="#" editable-text="user.name" e-onChange="alert('I am Fired')" e-style="color: green" e-required e-placeholder="Enter name">

OR
$('#username').on('save', function(e, params) {
alert('Saved value: ' + params.newValue);
});
: @wolffer-east

Comment: This doesn't show how to invoke code on your controller.  It seems that inside the e-onChange you don't have access to the controller, which is what most applications would need in order to implement complex application logic as a result of the change.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `e-ng-change` to add a callback like this:

```
<span editable-select="user.status" e-name="status" 
    e-ng-change="onStatusChanged($data)" 
    e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
```

Here is a fiddle where the Status selectbox will fire the Controller method `onStatusChanged`:

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/9713/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the success or error callback functions for basic X-Editable without Angular.
See http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable